# UITextView placement acting weird with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uitextview

I have a UITextView that is acting really weird why I try to constrain it with autolayout. The background will be placed right, but the text within is out of place. I tried to create an UIView, and then add it to the UIView instead, but the problem still persists.

Here is the UITextView and UIView declarations

```
let noteTextView: UITextView =
{
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.textColor = UIColor.white
    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    tv.isEditable = false
    tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return tv
}()

let backgroundView: UIView =
{
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 156, green: 44, blue: 252)

    return view
}()
```

And here is the constraints (using an extension called anchor)

```
    view.addSubview(backgroundView)
    backgroundView.addSubview(noteTextView)

    backgroundView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 65, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, paddingBottom: 0, width: 0, height: 80)

    noteTextView.anchor(top: backgroundView.topAnchor, left: backgroundView.leftAnchor, bottom: backgroundView.bottomAnchor, right: backgroundView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 2, paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight: 5, paddingBottom: 2, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Here is a video to demonstrate the problem: https://streamable.com/y8v70

Note: When I just added the UITextView to the view (without the UIVIew) the exact same thing happened.

Comment: why you don't use a UILabel?

Comment: Because the text can be quite long, and I don't know how many lines it will have as I fetch the text from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Try also:

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;  
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

May this help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not give a static height to UIView or to UITextView.

Try this Function:

```
func textviewHeight() {

        let contentSize = self.TextView.sizeThatFits(self.TextView.bounds.size)
        var frame = self.TextView.frame
        frame.size.height = contentSize.height
        self.TextView.frame = frame

        self.aspectRatioTextView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.TextView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.TextView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: TextView.bounds.height/TextView.bounds.width, constant: 1)
        self.TextView.addConstraint(self.aspectRatioTextView!)

        self.mainViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.mainViewHeightConstraint.constant + self.TextView.frame.height
    }
```

May be it helps you !!!!!